# How confirm saving file in SlimerJS

Tags: javascript, download, slimerjs

i want saving file from url, but open iframe where i can confirm action. But how confirm action with PhantomJs

```
var url = 'http://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs/archive/master.zip'; // example, this url link to file
page.open(url )
    .then(function(status){        
        if(status == "success") {            
           // open window where i can confirm my actions
        }       
     })
```

Comment: There is definetly no confirmation dialog in PhantomJS. Maybe there is one in SlimerJS. You haven't provided all the necessary information to help you. What sort of confirmation dialog is that supposed to be (from browser or part of the page)? Please provide the necessary markup and if possible images.

Comment: i`m not have reputation for add image(( but this good example
https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs/archive/master.zip
open this link and open dialog box

Comment: @ArtjomB. maybe i can download this file without this dialog box?